# Action listener in Java wait

Tags: java, actionlistener

Trying to make a nifty little program, but I think it's trying to run the code with the GET request, without waiting for the user input.
It's not that much code, so if you could help me by directing me to a resource where I could find info to fix that issue it'd be awesome.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader rd;
        OutputStreamWriter wr;
        String movie = null;
        Console console = System.console();
        movie = console.readLine("Enter input:");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=" + movie);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            line = rd.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry! That's not a valid URL.");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException codeyellow) {
             System.err.println("Caught UnknownHostException: " + codeyellow.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Off-site resource requests are off topic. Where's the problem in the above code.

Comment: I tried your code and it works without any changes(other than adding imports).. I use open jdk 1.7..

Comment: From the API -> "Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any." It probably means as soon as you have multiple programms and their consoles run in for example eclipse this method will rather return null than any of the attached consoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives a `NullPointerException` on that line:

```
movie = console.readLine("Enter input:");
```

That means that the console object doesn't get initialized.

Try reading input like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter input:");
movie = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: Man theres always someone faster than me :P +1 :)

Comment: Thanks so much! What does the .nextline() snippet do?

Comment: @user2783985 It reads the next available line from user input :)

Comment: I see! Also, I forgot the name of the thing which can parse the return data, would you happen to know the name of that?

Comment: @user2783985 Can you be more specific? I can't understand what you're talking about :/

Comment: @EricLang **No,** it's JSON.